# How can I play .ram audio files without installing the Real Audio Player?

Tags: audio, vlc-media-player, audio-streaming, realplayer, realmedia

I want to listen to an audio file on this [BBC French language learning](http://www.bbc.co.uk/apps/ifl/languages/french/news/quizengine?quiz=frnews_womens_magazines;templateStyle=frnews_womens_magazines) site.

However, the problem is that the audio file is a **.ram** file and from experience I don't want to install the Real Audio Player on my computer since it acts as adware, continually pops up, and is difficult to remove.

When I click on the .ram link, it asks me if I want to play it in my **VLC media player**, which attempts it but doesn't actually play or advance the play bar:

[image]

The **Windows Media Player** attempts to change the format then fails:

[image]

And **Winamp** does the same as VLC, actually opens it and pretends to play it but doesn't advance the play bar:

[image]

**How can I play this .ram audio file without installing Real Audio Player?**

Comment: have you tried "real alternative"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RealAudio#Players), Real Alternative requires the original RealPlayer to be installed.

It seems the only player that can play it "out of the box" is [MPlayer](http://www1.mplayerhq.hu/design7/dload.html). Downloads [here](http://www1.mplayerhq.hu/design7/dload.html).

Comment: According to [this blog](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/play-real-media-audio-using-vlc/), you can play .ram files with VLC.